# I want to merge launchers and active window programmes in XFCE4-Panel

Tags: xubuntu, launcher, xfce, dock

[image]

I want to merge `Visual Studio Code [The blue one]` and `Google Chrome` launchers with their respective `active window buttons` what can I do? Also, I don't want to use any external dock for XFCE4, only XFCE4-Panel is allowed. WHAT's the solution?

Comment: You would need to find or create a panel plugin that does that if one exists. The default Window button plugin does not work this way.

Comment: Do you know any plugin that can support this?

Comment: Not immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use two panels in XFCE4. I think there's no such panel plugin. That's why using `plank` or `dockbarx` will fullfil our necessities. For performance `plank` will use `15.3 MB` Memory and XFCE4-panel will use `64.5 MB` Memory of your system.

Attaching whisper menu to plank is not that much productive because when we click on the `whisker menu` that is attached in `plank`, it will lag in some sort.

So, using `xfce4-panel` at the top with the whisker menu in it and plank below will smooth your performance.

Codes:

1. Install plank: `sudo apt install plank`
2. Run whisker menu: `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu -p`

If you want to attach `whiskermenu` in `plank` you can create a `whiskermenu` launcher in Desktop and drag-drop it to plank. Use the upper code in launcher.

Comment: Thanks but I am keenly in search of plugin that can do such task. Is there any way we can create such XFCE4 (linux) plugin in Python?